# TBB и K-means Clustering(на С++)

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Ночь добрая, у меня возникла проблема с parallel_for

a точнее с изменением K-means Clustering алгоритма на параллельно работающую версию.(Задание таково) Оригинальный код выглядит так.

```
virtual void compute(const std::vector<POINT> &points, std::size_t k, std::size_t iters,
    std::vector<POINT> &centroids, std::vector<ASGN> &assignments)
{
    // Prepare for the first iteration
    centroids.resize(k);
    assignments.resize(points.size());
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < k; ++i)
        centroids[i] = points[i];

    // Run the k-means refinements
    while (iters > 0) {
        --iters;

        // Prepare empty tmp fields.
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
            sums[i].x = sums[i].y = 0;
            counts[i] = 0;
        }

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i) {
            std::size_t nearest = getNearestCluster(points[i], centroids);
            assignments[i] = (ASGN)nearest;
            sums[nearest].x += points[i].x;
            sums[nearest].y += points[i].y;
            ++counts[nearest];
        }

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
            if (counts[i] == 0) continue;   // If the cluster is empty, keep its previous centroid.
            centroids[i].x = sums[i].x / (std::int64_t)counts[i];
            centroids[i].y = sums[i].y / (std::int64_t)counts[i];
        }
    }
}
```

по изменению 2 фор цикла на parallel_for

```
            parallel_for(blocked_range<size_t>(0, pointsSize),
            [=](const blocked_range<size_t>& r) {


            for (std::size_t i = r.begin(); i < r.end(); ++i) {
                std::size_t nearest = getNearestCluster(points[i], centroids);
                assignments[i] = (ASGN)nearest;
                sums[nearest].x += points[i].x;
                sums[nearest].y += points[i].y;
                ++counts[nearest];
            }
        });
```

У меня начала появляться ошибка в данном месте assignments[i] = (ASGN)nearest;

> Error C3892   'std::vector>::operator []': you cannot assign to a variable that is const  kmeans-parrarel

Примечание, я не могу менять аргументы функции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из [документации](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

> Если ключевое слово mutable не было использовано в лямбда-выражении,
>   объекты, захваченные копированием, немодифицируемы внутри этого
>   operator()

Вы как раз захватываете по значению. Поэтому используйте либо ключевое слово mutable, либо берите по ссылке.